# Svelte: how to spyOn functions specified in template using jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte, testing-library

I have a Svelte component that imports a function and then provides that function as a click handler in the template. I would like to spyOn and mock this function using jest.
After mocking the function, any calls to functions that call the mocked function work as expected, but clicking on the element that uses the function as a handler results in the real function being called and not the mock.  A

Here is a codesandbox with the issue https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-fast-uxgqe?file=/app.test.js

```
test-util.ts
export const foo = () => console.log('real foo');
export const bar = () => foo();
```

```
Test.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import { foo, bar } from '@utils/test-util';
</script>

<button on:click={foo} data-testid="foo">foo</button>
<button on:click={bar} data-testid="bar">bar</button>
```

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import Test from '@components/Test.svelte';
import * as testUtil from '@utils/test-util';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('fails', async () => {
  const fooMock = jest
    .spyOn(testUtil, 'foo')
    .mockImplementation(() => console.log('mock foo'));
  const testComponent = render(Test);
  await userEvent.click(testComponent.getByTestId('bar')); // logs 'mock foo'
  await userEvent.click(testComponent.getByTestId('foo')); // logs 'real foo'
  expect(fooMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // fails, actual value 1
});
```

Short of adding an intermediary function like bar just for the sake of testing, how would I approach mocking foo so that the mock is called when used as a handler?

Comment: Could you setup a codesandbox with the non working example? I think you'll get more people looking into it then.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-fast-uxgqe?file=/app.test.js

Comment: Just a note, but it seems you're trying to test a little too low level for a Svelte component test. Instead consider integration testing the component based on changes to the DOM or other user-facing events and then separately unit-test the foo/bar methods.